# Parse command-line arguments as ByteString

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Is there a cross-platform way to parse program arguments into a list of `ByteString` (instead of a list of `String`, as in [`System.Environment.getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs))?

I am aware of [`System.Posix.Env.ByteString.getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Env-ByteString.html#v:getArgs) from the [`unix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0) package, but I would like to be able to run my program on Windows without cygwin. I am also aware of [`Data.ByteString.Char8.pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack), but that truncates characters to 8 bits, and I would like to be able to process any <s>Unicode character</s> sequence of bytes.

EDIT: My program is a simple cipher which xor's the bits of the key against the bits of the message. For that reason, I would prefer to process the exact bits that were provided to the program instead of translating them into UTF-8 and back first.

Comment: `fromString` function in Data.ByteString.UTF8 "converts a Haskell string into a UTF8 encoded bytestring." - see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-0.3.8/docs/Data-ByteString-UTF8.html

Comment: @w.b That may work, but ideally I want to process the argument in the character-encoding scheme in which it was provided (e.g. UTF-16).

Comment: If you want to process Unicode, why don't you use `Text`? ByteString isn't really that Unicode friendly. Apart from that issue, you could transform the `String` to a `CStringLen` and create a `ByteString` from that. After all, you're already in `IO`.

Comment: "process the argument in the character-encoding scheme in which it was provided". Why? Normally one wants to forget about the encoding ASAP, and work with characters rather than their codes. Anyway, Unix arguments may be sequences of bytes, but Windows arguments are not, they are sequences of characters.

Comment: I am not necessarily process Unicode; what's important for my purposes is processing the straight bits. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @n.m. So are Windows arguments guaranteed to be in a certain character-encoding scheme?

Comment: Why? Why encoding schemes? Who needs them? The users certainly don't type any encoding schemes as they run your program. They type characters. You get characters they type. Who needs to know how these characters travel from the keyboard to your program?

Comment: As for Windows, yes, it operates in UTF-16 internally, or maybe in UCS-2, who knows. They probably can't tell the difference themselves. Why anyone should care, I have no idea.

Comment: How about using a `String` with `ord` and `chr`?

Comment: @DavidYoung Unfortunately no; I need to compare bytes from one source to bytes from another source, and `ord`/`chr` would yield Unicode codepoints above 255, which I would need to translate into bytes, and there's no certainty that the method I might use to do so would match the character-encoding scheme in which it was provided (if it is indeed provided in a valid character-encoding scheme).

Comment: I think that you're going to have to copy the sources from `System.Environment` - if you look at these sources, `getArgs` converts to the system encoding at the last moment, it reads the data as "raw bytes". It seems that the code you want already exists, the piece you want is simply not exported as a function.